# Why does » show up as « when I use the font quicksand in google fonts?

Tags: html, utf-8, character, webfonts, google-webfonts

I want to print out a "»" on a webpage. I write the character using UTF-8 (no charcode just the character)

Using the specific font "Quicksand" font-weight 700 from google web-font dierectory, it points to the left rather than the right. Other fonts from the dierectory works fine.

The character I want is called 
&raquo but the one I get is «

They are also refered to as:
Angle quote mark, left, charcode: &#171;
Angle quote mark, right charcode: &#187;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably because there is an error in the font file. Report it to Google.

Comment: This particular bug exists in the bold (700) version of the font only. The normal (400) and Book (300) versions are OK for ‘»’ but have an empty (blank) glyph for its partner ‘«’! See http://jsfiddle.net/NhPjy/

Comment: Jukkula, you are a pride to this community! Thank you so much!

Comment: btw I mailed the font-designer and google-web-fonts about this.

Answer (score 1):

Force that character to normal font weight, for example with:

```
<span style="font-weight:normal">&raquo;</span>
```

Despite being at least a 3 year old mistake, no-one can be bothered to fix the font.

Comment: You should add this as a comment to the answer above so that people don't miss it!